# Download and upload of a file in PHP does not work in updated Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a project which was working fine till yesterday.
My chrome is updated to the recent version. The issue is that my download and upload of file does not work.
But when I degrade the Chrome version it seems to work fine.
May I know the reason for this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Following is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="worklist_upload_form" onsubmit="return worklist_upload(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload_worklist" id="upload_worklist" style="width:200px;" accept=".csv" />
</form>
```

Following is my js code:

```
function worklist_upload(){
    if(document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value == ""){
        //document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").style.display = "block";
     dispmsg("error","Warning","Please upload the worklist");
    //  document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").innerHTML = "<img src='images/red_wrong.png' width='12' alt='wrong' /> Please upload the worklist";
        document.getElementById("upload_worklist").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value != ""){  
        var fileName = document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value;
        var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if( ext == "xls" || ext == "xlsx") {
            //return true;
        }else{
      dispmsg("error","Warning","Please select .xls or .xlsx format");
        /*  document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").innerHTML = "<img src='images/red_wrong.png' width='12' alt='wrong' /> Please select .csv or xls format";
            document.getElementById("upload_worklist").focus();*/
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe some errors in your console? Please provide more information

Comment: You might have been relying on deprecated or bugged behaviour which was removed/patched.

Comment: @Volodymyr I dont get any errors in my console.

Comment: Then post some example code, so we can test it for ourselves.

Comment: @apokryfos Please could u elaborate on what u are trying to say.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it is just the basic input type file.

Comment: So it would be easy for you to give an example...

Comment: Can you post your HTML form code? You've to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Also can you explain more about the `download` part?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the php template Smarty is being used. Is this an issue with updated chrome version????

Comment: It might be, it might not be, no way to tell without any code, or a way for us to test your claim ourselves.

Comment: For example [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/chrome-69-deps-rems) says that with Chrome 69  `window.confirm` will not work with background windows/tabs so if you used one to download with a confirmation it would not work. I have no idea what you are doing though, if your question is whether the newer Chrome version broke downloads in general that is not the case.

Comment: You should check whether `worklist_upload()` does indeed return 'true'.

Comment: Is this JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: @MatrixCow08 It looks like HTML with a tiny bit of Javascript in it.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the `action=""` part which maybe posts data to the same PHP file. However, this is still not a good example code.

Comment: I have added the js code.

Comment: don't know what the issue is, but change `action=""` to `action="http://dumpinput.ratma.net/"` and run it both on old chrome and new chrome, and compare the output of both, what differences do you get?

Comment: Why is the `return true` commented out in the Javascript?

Comment: On line 14 of your JavaScript code, try to uncomment the `return true;` part

Comment: I also noticed that your form allows .csv files, but your javascript looks for Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

On your JavaScript code, it is better to check if `ext` **NOT** equals .xls or .xlsx and display the error if it doesn't equal.

So your JavaScript code should be like that:

```
function worklist_upload(){
    if(document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value == ""){
        //document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").style.display = "block";
     dispmsg("error","Warning","Please upload the worklist");
    //  document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").innerHTML = "<img src='images/red_wrong.png' width='12' alt='wrong' /> Please upload the worklist";
        document.getElementById("upload_worklist").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value != ""){  
        var fileName = document.getElementById("upload_worklist").value;
        var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if( ext !== "xls" && ext !== "xlsx") {
            dispmsg("error","Warning","Please select .xls or .xlsx format");
        /*  document.getElementById("error_upload_worklist").innerHTML = "<img src='images/red_wrong.png' width='12' alt='wrong' /> Please select .csv or xls format";
            document.getElementById("upload_worklist").focus();*/
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your HTML form accepts `.csv` while your JavaScript code checks for `.xls` or `.xlsx`

---

**EDIT**: You can also check if the extension wasn't `.xls` or `.xlsx` by another way instead of `if( ext !== "xls" && ext !== "xlsx")` which is:

```
if(["xls","xlsx"].indexOf(ext) == -1) {
    // Display error messages
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `((ext !== "xls") || (ext !== "xlsx"))` will always be true. Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Yes, was a mistake. Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: Guys the code is just a sample one.... The issue is in the entire project. After upgrading the chrome all the file uploads and downloads are not working. The issue is seen in IE 11 also.

Comment: @Thilagam - Then you've coded something that works for the old browsers' versions only. You've to see if you're using deprectated functions and replace them with functions that work on all the browsers & their versions.